# DOMDocument->saveHtml() escape utf8 in script tag

Tags: php, symfony, utf-8

```
$newContent = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=ru>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Кирилица</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Кирилица
  <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    function drawCharts(){
      console.log('Кирилица');
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
HTML;

$crawler = new \Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler($newContent);
$newContent = $crawler->html();
// here is a fix, that can unescape all escaped chars
// $newContent = preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", function($m) { 
//   return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); 
// }, $newContent);

var_dump($newContent);
```

so... my question is:
why utf8 chars(cyrilic symbols) escaped only inside the script tag? O_o
. . . . . . . . . . . . . .

Comment: I encountered similar problem before. It was a JSON data that was escaped. Try not to dump but to render it in browser.

Comment: Your question has the symfony1 and symfony2 tags. Please use only the tag corresponding to your Symfony version.